# Print multiple matching element names

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm attempting to print the names of multiple elements, but I can only convince XPath to output one.

Given this XML:

```
<xml>
    <foob>931</foob>
    <arba>478</arba>
    <zfoo>892</zfoo>
</xml>
```

I try this and get `foob`:

```
name(//*[contains(name(), "foo")])
```

I try this and get an error about an invalid expression:

```
//*[contains(name(), "foo")]/name()
```

Although this works fine:

```
//*[contains(name(), "foo")]/text()
```

I'm on the command line, and have tried both `xmllint` and `xpath` (from Perl's XML-XPath module) with the same results.

How can I get *both* `foob` and `zfoo` returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With **XPath 1.0**, your first XPath,

```
name(//*[contains(name(), "foo")])
```

results in just `"foob"` because XPath 1.0 passes only the first member of the selected nodeset to `name()`.  To obtain a list of `"foob"` and `"zfoo"`, you would have to iterate over the selected nodeset in the language hosting the XPath call -- XSLT, Python, Java, etc.

With **XPath 2.0**, your second XPath,

```
//*[contains(name(), "foo")]/name()
```

would work fine to obtain a list of `"foob"` and `"zfoo"` directly via XPath alone.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't aware the second was XPath 2.0; there seem to be not many CLI parsers that support it. Will have to write something up in Python or PHP. Thanks!